# How to make a very short zoom-in zoom-out effect on the highlighted text using CSS / jquery, triggered by a user input?

Tags: jquery, css

I am searching for a way, how to make a very short zoom-in zoom-out effect on the highlighted text using CSS and jquery.

Background: on a website, I have a search input box. When a user enters a symbol, the result automatically shows up (no need for pressing enter). In this result we mark the found part of the string with `<b>` tags `</b>` for CSS-styling:

```
Example:
Search input: {empty}     Result: code
Search input: c           Result: <b>c</b>ode
Search input: co          Result: <b>co</b>de
```

Basically, I want to achieve a short zoom-in zoom-out effect, as the user enters a symbol, so that there would be a visual feedback.

I have a function that gets executed each time, the user enters a symbol in the search box. The only part missing, is the CSS / jquery for the animation that can be executed in such function.

CSS code for `<b>` tags `</b>` highlighting:

```
.title.horizontal-line b {
  background-color:#FCFE9A;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a minimal example. Read more about [css animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations).

```js
$('input').on('input change',function() {
  $('.output').html(`<b>${$('input').val()}</b>de`);
})
```

```css
b {
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-name: grow;
}

@keyframes grow {
  0%   {font-size: 100%;}
  50%  {font-size: 150%;}
  100% {font-size: 100%;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
enter some text:<input type="text"/>
<div class="output"></div>
```

@Abinthaha's solution of using `transform:scale` didn't work with my markup, because you can't apply that to inline elements. If you like that better for some reason, just change the animated element to `block` or `inline-block`:

```js
$('input').on('input change',function() {
  $('.output').html(`<b>${$('input').val()}</b>de`);
})
```

```css
b {
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-name: grow;
  display:inline-block;
}

@keyframes grow {
    0%   {transform: scale(1.0, 1.0);}
    50%  {transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);}
    100% {transform: scale(1.0, 1.0);}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
enter some text:<input type="text"/>
<div class="output"></div>
```

Comment: Worked great! Thanks! Interestingly didn't work with transform: scale.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it work using CSS3 animations as follows:

```
.title.horizontal-line b {
    background-color:#FCFE9A;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}
@keyframes zoom {
    0%   {transform: scale(1.0, 1.0);}
    50%  {transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);}
    100% {transform: scale(1.0, 1.0);}
}
```

This will add an animation with zoom-in and zoom-out effect as you said. Now, this is set for 4 seconds. That means, it will zoom-in for the first two seconds and zoom-out for the next 2 seconds. 
To shorten the delay, reduce the time. 
If you want to repeat the same for more than one time, there is a property called `animation-iteration-count`. Its value can be set from `1, 2, 3, .., infinity`.